# delete using union in mysql?

Tags: mysql, union, sql-delete

i want to delete id = 142.

the two tables are:

1)user_master_activate 2)user_master tables

using union where both tables have same column.

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM user_master_activate UNION SELECT * FROM user_master ) AS U WHERE (U.id = '142')
```

> this is working where i am getting all users record

```
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM user_master_activate UNION SELECT * FROM user_master ) AS U WHERE U.id = '142'
```

Comment: check your syntax on the manual

Comment: From which table you need to delete? "user_master_activate " or "user_master " or both?

Comment: its in the 1) user_master_activate table if that id is not there delete from 2) user_master table

Comment: both table have same column , i don't know on which table "id"  is there, for getting that id, i am using union to make both tables in one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete data from `user_master_activate` using below query:

```
DELETE FROM user_master_activate WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM user_master_activate WHERE id = '142'
 UNION 
 SELECT id FROM user_master WHERE id = '142')
```

You can delete data from `user_master` using below query:

```
 DELETE FROM user_master WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM user_master_activate WHERE id = '142'
 UNION 
 SELECT id FROM user_master WHERE id = '142')
```

**Soultion2:**
Not tested

```
DELETE
FROM user_master
    ,user_master_activate USING user_master
INNER JOIN user_master_activate ON user_master.id = user_master_activate.id
WHERE user_master.id = '142';
```

Comment: can it be in one query , i dont have issue in 2 just ask for curiosity.

Comment: I have added one more solution please check

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with just a single query for the delete statement. With a select statement it works because it is just reading the result of the query. For the deletion it won't work because you need to specify the name of the table from where the deletion will be done. The way you are using the delete statement is not the correct synthax.

See [Delete Synthax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) in the MySQL official docs for more information.

I would recommend you run the deletion as two commands:

```
 DELETE FROM user_master_activate WHERE id='142';
 DELETE FROM user_master WHERE id='142';
```

If the tables are related, then start by deleting the child, then the parent data, else the order of deletion wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` is used only with `SELECT` statements:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

If you don't want to use two separate `DELETE` statements and those two tables are related, try using the `JOIN` statement:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two separate queries since you are deleting in multiple tables,

```
DELETE FROM user_master_activate WHERE id = '142'
DELETE FROM user_master WHERE id = '142'
```

However, MySQL supports [cascade delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) but you have to configure foreign key in the referencing table.

```
CREATE TABLE user_master
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    -- ... other columns here 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_master_activate
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    -- ... other columns here 
    FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES user_master(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And you will have only one delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM user_master WHERE id = '142'
```

All rows the referencing to `user_master` in table `user_master_activate` will also be deleted.